# SQL Dialect Configuration On Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The application is built with JHipster/Spring Boot and PostgreSQL as its repository. Based on [this article](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/postgresqls-jsonb-type-mapping-using-hibernate/), I have a custom UserType class and a SQL dialect class as the following

```
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {

  public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
    this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
  }
}
```

And I have its configuration in application.xml file as

```
spring:
    ...
    jpa:
        open-in-view: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
                implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.dialect: com.abc.customdatatypes.usertype.CustomPostgreSQLDialect
```

For an integration test,

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void createProduct() throws Exception {
    int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = productRepository.findAll().size();

    // Create the Product
    restProductMockMvc.perform(post("/api/products")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(product)))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    // Validate the Product in the database
    List<Product> productList = productRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(productList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
    Product testProduct = productList.get(productList.size() - 1);
    assertThat(testProduct.getBrand()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_BRAND);
    assertThat(testProduct.getName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_NAME);
    assertThat(testProduct.getKeywords()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_KEYWORDS);
    assertThat(testProduct.getSpecs()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_SPECS);
    assertThat(testProduct.getSeason()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_SEASON);

    // Validate the Product in Elasticsearch
    verify(mockProductSearchRepository, times(1)).save(testProduct);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2000
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:70)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:101)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:346)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:231)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:156)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
... 68 more
```

It seems that the SQL dialect configuration has no effect. I add the same line of configuration to application-dev.yml as well as application-prod.xml without a luck.

Is a way to find out whether the SQL dialect configuration has an effect or not?

Comment: Connection string?

Comment: The error isn't about DB connection. It occurs regardless whether the DB connection is up or not.

Comment: Please supply connection string regardles of what you think.

Comment: What is a connection string? As a Jhipster project, such configuration is set up already without any manual intervention.

Comment: answer changed - you have wrong config path/.

Answer (score 3):

Correct config key is

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect
```

while yours effectively is

`spring.jpa.properties.dialect`

It would be easier for you if you would use `properties` file instead of `yaml`

Comment: Why? The generated project comes with configuration YAML files. It won't be good to change the configuration file format nor add another one.

Comment: I try to understand why the configuration leads to spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.

Comment: https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: Cuz setting dialect is hibernate configuration property not JPA, nor Spring, and thats how you configure it using persistence.xml

Comment: I already mentioned an article where my code is based. The configuration shall be the same as the reference you provide, just in different format. That shall lead to the same outcome.

Comment: Did you even try that ?

Comment: If you mean change the configuration file format from YAML to property, I don't make such change. I won't change JHipster configuration file format.

Comment: I mean, did you check if changed config key has any effect.

Comment: The test database is configured for H2 in JHipster. That is the cause.

Comment: And how that answers my question ? :)